# Google Spreadsheet - M2M Concatenator

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, concatenation, spreadsheet, string-concatenation

[image]

I have an issue with Google Spreadsheet. From the example table above, I want to generate exactly like column C. I understand that this cannot be achieved using regular formulas alone, but requires a script. Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: "I understand that this cannot be achieved using regular formulas alone" <-- you can. Since your blocks are delineated in Column A, you can always search for the end of the block using `sort(row(...`, or if your centralize your formulas with `scan`, using `offset` and check blank, and the rest is straight-forward. But also see the above comment. You can use [this link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) to share an editable sheet anonymously if you wish. (Remember to make your example sheet editable either way.)

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to the following formula-

```
=LET(
lr,COUNTA(B1:B),
y,A1:INDEX(A1:A,lr),
z,B1:INDEX(B1:B,lr),
MAP(y,LAMBDA(t,IF(t="","",TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER(z,SCAN(,y,LAMBDA(p,q,IF(q="",p,q)))=t)))))
)
```

[image]

Comment: That code is work like charm! But run smothly in small data range like above example.
I applied it in my more 2000 rows data, and my browser tab is freezing.

Comment: After a while, it's show an Error : Calculation limit was reached while trying to compute this formula.

Comment: @wahyueka31 Try edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Google Apps Script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and save the script. When you use this script, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE(A2:B)` into a cell "C2". By this, the result values are returned.

```js
function SAMPLE(values) {
  const len = values.length;
  const { rows } = values.slice().reverse().reduce((o, [a], i) => {
    o.c++;
    if (a !== "" || i == len - 1) {
      o.rows.push(o.c);
      o.c = 0;
    }
    return o;
  }, { c: 0, rows: [] });
  rows.reverse();
  const res = rows.flatMap(e => [[values.splice(0, e).map(([, b]) => b).filter(String).join(",")], ...Array(e - 1).fill([null])]);
  return res;
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained. In my test, this custom function could be used for 6,000 rows.

[image]

#### Note:

If the custom function cannot be used, please test the following script. In this script, the values are retrieved from cells "A2:B" and put the result to cells "C2:C". When I tested this script with 6,000 rows, the process time was about 3 seconds.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues();
  const len = values.length;
  const { rows } = values.slice().reverse().reduce((o, [a], i) => {
    o.c++;
    if (a !== "" || i == len - 1) {
      o.rows.push(o.c);
      o.c = 0;
    }
    return o;
  }, { c: 0, rows: [] });
  rows.reverse();
  const res = rows.flatMap(e => [[values.splice(0, e).map(([, b]) => b).join(",")], ...Array(e - 1).fill([null])]);
  range.offset(0, 2, res.length, 1).setValues(res);
}
```

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following LAMBDA-less solution, it won't run into calculation limit but it could be slow because it creates a 2D array that has the size of the amount of rows in column B from row 2 up to the last non-empty row.

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(a_,A2:A,
       b_,B2:B,
       a,SINGLE(a_):INDEX(a_,MATCH(,0/LEN(b_))),
       b,SINGLE(b_):INDEX(b_,MATCH(,0/LEN(b_))),
       cc,COUNTIFS(a,"<>",ROW(a),"<="&ROW(a)),
       SUBSTITUTE(
         SUBSTITUTE(
           TRIM(TOCOL(
             QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(IF(cc=TOROW(a),b,)," ","ζ"),,9E+99))),
           " ",", "),
         "ζ"," ")))
```

[image]

**Note:** This formula assumes that the values in column A do not repeat.